# Latex to XML using pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, xml

I am writing Latex to `XML`. While compiling `pdflatex` we generate a `xml` file using `\immediate\write{text}` in tagged commands. But how can i get normal text to `XML` file. Can any one explain with samples.

Comment: Related: [Converting ConTeXt document to HTML](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43052/converting-context-document-to-html)

Answer (score 11):

I don't know about the possible solutions with LaTeX and pdftex engine, but ConTeXt MkIV (which uses LuaTeX engine) supports an XML backend that is used to generate [EPUB](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/epub) and [tagged PDF](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/PDFX).

To get the XML output from a file, you need to add

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]
```

As an example, consider a simple file with some figures, math, and lists.

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]
\setuppapersize[A5]
\starttext

\startsection[title={Sample Section}]

  \startplacefigure
      [location=right, title={A sample figure}]
      \externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]
  \stopplacefigure

  \input knuth

  \placeformula[eq:1]
  \startformula
    E = mc^2 
  \stopformula

  Einstein gave the expression~(\in[eq:1]).

  \startitemize[n]
    \startitem
      First point
    \stopitem

    \startitem
      Second point
    \stopitem
  \stopitemize
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

which generates the following PDF output

[image]

In addition, it generates the following XML file `\jobname.export` (notice that all the structural information is retained and math is exported to MathML)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>

<!-- input filename   : test              -->
<!-- processing date  : Tue Dec  4 00:21:55 2012 -->
<!-- context version  : 2012.11.16 23:51  -->
<!-- exporter version : 0.30              -->


<document language="en" file="test" date="Tue Dec  4 00:21:55 2012" context="2012.11.16 23:51" version="0.30" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <section detail="section" location='aut:1'>
    <sectionnumber>1</sectionnumber> 
    <sectiontitle>Sample Section</sectiontitle> 
    <sectioncontent>
      <float detail="figure" location='aut:2'>
        <floatcontent><image name="cow" id='image-1' width='2.000cm' height='1.455cm'></image></floatcontent>
        <floatcaption><floatlabel detail="figure">Figure </floatlabel><floatnumber detail="figure">1</floatnumber> <floattext>A sample figure</floattext></floatcaption>
      </float>
Thus, I came to the conclusion that the designer of a new system must not only be the implementer and first large--scale user; the designer should also write the first user manual.
      <break/>
The separation of any of these four components would have hurt TEX significantly. If I had not participated fully in all these activities, literally hundreds of improvements would never have been made, because I would never have thought of them or perceived why they were important.
      <break/>
But a system cannot be successful if it is too strongly influenced by a single person. Once the initial design is complete and fairly robust, the real test begins as people with many different viewpoints undertake their own experiments.
      <formula>
        <formulacontent>
          <m:math display="block">
            <m:mrow>
              <m:mi></m:mi>
              <m:mo>=</m:mo>
              <m:mi></m:mi>
              <m:msup>
                <m:mi></m:mi>
                <m:mn>2</m:mn>
              </m:msup>
            </m:mrow>
          </m:math>
        </formulacontent>
        <formulacaption>(<formulanumber detail="formula">1</formulanumber>)</formulacaption> 
      </formula>
Einstein gave the expression&#xA0;(1). 
      <itemgroup detail="itemize" symbol="n">
        <item>
          <itemtag>1.</itemtag>
          <itemcontent>First point</itemcontent>
        </item>
        <item>
          <itemtag>2.</itemtag>
          <itemcontent>Second point</itemcontent>
        </item>
      </itemgroup>
    </sectioncontent>
  </section>
</document>
```

Two auxiliary `css` files are also generated, the first `\jobname-style.css` which contains css for the font setup and any ConTeXt defined environments and colors:

```
/* styles for file test.export */

document {
    font-size  : 12pt !important ;
    max-width  : 300pt !important ;
    text-align : justify !important ;
    hyphens    : inherited !important ;
}
```

and a `\jobname-images.css` file that contains information about the images used in the tex file.

```
/* images for file test.export */

image[id="image-1"] {
    display           : block ;
    background-image  : url(cow) ;
    background-size   : 100% auto ;
    background-repeat : no-repeat ;
    width             : 2.000cm ;
    height            : 1.455cm ;
}
```

Comment: @mu30 is possible to write the structure  \immediate\write{text}?

Comment: @mu30 I think you had implemented in your old office Digritech!!!. Could you help how to create the XML file through \write command?

Answer (score 6):

I think there is also another way: [LaTeXML: A LaTeX to XML Converter](http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/).

After having install it, one might proceed as follows.

Consider the following MWE called `test_xml.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Here is some text that precedes the image.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ctan_lion} % http://www.ctan.org/lion.html
\end{figure}

Here is a formula:
\begin{equation}
e=mc^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

We have one external module, `graphicx`, that could be bind directly: see (Loading Bindings) page 5 of the manual and the appendix B. Thus we just have to do with the terminal:

```
latexml --preload=graphicx.sty --preload=LaTeX.pool --destination=test_xml.xml test_xml
```

and the resultant `test_xml.xml` will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?latexml searchpaths=".,//home/claudio/Scrivania/prova/"?>
<?latexml package="graphicx"?>
<?latexml options="a4paper,11pt" class="article"?>
<?latexml package="graphicx"?>
<?latexml RelaxNGSchema="LaTeXML"?>
<document xmlns="http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML">
  <para xml:id="p1">
    <p>Here is some text that precedes the image.</p>
  </para>
  <figure refnum="1" xml:id="S0.F1">
    <graphics graphic="ctan_lion" options="scale=0.5"/>
    <!-- %http://www.ctan.org/lion.html -->
  </figure>
  <para xml:id="p2">
    <p>Here is a formula:</p>
    <equation refnum="1" xml:id="S0.E1">
      <Math mode="display" tex="e=mc^{2}" xml:id="S0.E1.m1" text="e = m * c ^ 2">
        <XMath>
          <XMApp>
            <XMTok meaning="equals" role="RELOP">=</XMTok>
            <XMTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">e</XMTok>
            <XMApp>
              <XMTok meaning="times" role="MULOP">⁢</XMTok>
              <XMTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">m</XMTok>
              <XMApp>
                <XMTok role="SUPERSCRIPTOP" scriptpos="post2"/>
                <XMTok role="UNKNOWN" font="italic">c</XMTok>
                <XMTok meaning="2" role="NUMBER">2</XMTok>
              </XMApp>
            </XMApp>
          </XMApp>
        </XMath>
      </Math>
    </equation>
  </para>
</document>
```

Now, it is also possible to perform some postprocessing to obtain for example `.xhtml` or `.html` files (not only these files, of course, see the manual for reference).

For a `.xhtml` file:

```
latexmlpost --graphicimages --destination=test_xml.xhtml test_xml
```

For a `.html` file:

```
latexmlpost --format=html --graphicimages --destination=test_xml.html test_xml
```

These operations will convert formulas and images automatically (because of the `--graphicimages` option). The result will be something like:

[image]

Comment: I completed 100% result LaTeX to Xml with mathml equation.

Comment: Any one need LaTeX 2 XML contact Me