# Convert LaTeX to DAISY book

Tags: conversion, accessibility, audio

Is there an easy way to convert a LaTeX book into a DAISY book?

BTW: A Daisy book is a talking book for visually challenged users. It has both text and audio. You can directly export a document as a Daisy book from MS-WORD and LibreOffice.

Comment: I don't think so but converting from TeX to PDF and then PDF to DAISY seems like a viable route, although you will almost certainly have problems if your document contains mathematics.

Comment: @Andrew Not much mathematics in my document.Is there any free tool which I can use to convert pdf to DAISY?

Comment: Try searching: google turned up a few for me! I have no experience with using DAISY so I can't recommend anything....

Comment: You'd need a latex to xml converter, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85438/latex-to-xml-using-pdflatex

Comment: you can use `tex4ebook` to convert your document to `epub3`, it shouldn't be hard to convert it then to DAISY