# Can LuaTeX create HTML?

Tags: luatex, html

I heard that LuaTeX provides access to the internals of TeX. So, I have two questions in this regard:

- Is it possible to modify the output routine with LuaTeX so that HTML is produced instead of DVI or PDF?
- If possible, are there any projects aiming at this?

Comment: The answers to your questions are: yes and yes.  To be precise: ConTeXt MkIV (which is built on top of LuaTeX) can produce (X)HTML *natively* from ConTeXt source.  I'm not aware of any LaTeX package to do such a thing, though.

Comment: ConTeXt outputs XML. Most browswers display this XML, which can be styled using CSS, without problems. See [Converting ConTeXt document to HTML](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55945/5245) for a demonstration.

Comment: To add to what @Marco and @ mbork pointed out in their comments: Context does indeed produce XML out of the box, but it does not actuall need to “modify the output routine”.
(That’s actually pretty obvious since HTML doesn’t have the concept of a *page* like TeX does.)
Instead, the relevant structural commands are [extended to tag regions of text by means of Luatex attributes](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/back-exp.mkiv#l46), which doesn’t even require much effort since most user-level commands are derived from generic ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is possible to access nodes created by `\special` commands, we can access tags inserted by `tex4ht`. Small proof of concept is [lua4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/lua4ht) package.

Advantage is that it supports `fontspec` and `unicode-math` packages, which `tex4ht` doesn't support otherwise, the downside is that `mathml` production is broken, so it is produced as normal italic text in the sample. In theory, we can produce `mathml` directly from LuaTeX's math nodes, I've tried some exercises in this direction and it seemed doable.

Sample:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\section{Font support}

Příliš \textit{žluťoučký kůň} úpěl \textsc{ďábelské ódy}. A \textbf{další text}

\section{Math}

$\forall x \in X, \quad \exists y \leq \epsilon$

\section{Tables}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  hello & world\\
  hello & again\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

we need also small config file, `hej.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{textit}{\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\HCode{<strong>}}{\HCode{</strong>}}
\Configure{textsc}{\HCode{<span class="sc">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
\Configure{$}{\HCode{<span class="inline-math">}}{\HCode{</span>}}{}
\begin{document}
\Css{.sc{font-variant: small-caps;}}
\Css{.inline-math{font-style:italic;}}
\EndPreamble
```

compile with:

```
make4ht -b lua4ht -um draft -c hej.cfg  sample.tex  "new-accents"
```

and the result:

[image]

```xml
  <h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1 </span> <a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>Font support</h3> <!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" >Příliš <em>žluťoučký kůň</em> úpěl <span class="sc">ďábelské ódy</span>. A <strong>další text</strong>  </p><!--l. 12--><p class="noindent" > </p><h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">2 </span> <a 
 id="x1-20002"></a>Math</h3> <!--l. 14--><p class="noindent" ><span class="inline-math">∀∈, ∃≤</span>  </p><!--l. 16--><p class="noindent" > </p><h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">3 </span> <a 
 id="x1-30003"></a>Tables</h3><div class="tabular"> <table id="TBL-1" class="tabular" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  
><colgroup id="TBL-1-1g"><col 
id="TBL-1-1" /><col 
id="TBL-1-2" /></colgroup><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-1-"><td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-1-1"  
class="td11">  hello  </td><td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-1-2"  
class="td11">  world  </td></tr><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-2-"><td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-2-1"  
class="td11">  hello  </td><td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-2-2"  
class="td11">  again  </td></tr><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-3-"><td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:left;" id="TBL-1-3-1"  
class="td11">   </td></tr></table> </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to compile as instructed and receive: [ERROR]   htlatex: ? ?  LaTeX Error: File `lua4ht.sty' not found.
I have a proper texlive 2020 installation.

Comment: @tatojo it is not on CTAN and in TeX distributions. It is not in a usable state. Do you have problems with normal LuaTeX support in TeX4ht?

Comment: How to get the html file from your tex document with lualatex?

Comment: @tatojo it is best to use `make4ht -l filename.tex`. It uses LuaLaTeX for the compilation. It still uses the DVI file for the extraction, but it is the best solution in most cases. you can also try https://github.com/michal-h21/lua4ht, but I am not sure if it even works with current LuaLaTeX