# Images in HTML exported from ConTeXt

Tags: context

I am trying to assess ConTeXt as a source format for producing PDF and HTML output. I've discovered the feature:

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]
```

but running the example from [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43052/converting-context-document-to-html), does not result in the image being included in the html or xhtml output. The *docName*-export/images directory is empty and the HTML has comments where the image tags should be:

```
<div class="combinationcontent"><div class="image label-3.463cm" id="image-1"><!--empty--></div>
```

I am working on the assumption that all source files (.tex, .css, .png) should be stored in the same directory. PDFs build correctly.

I have Context 1.02 from TeX Live 2018 on OSX 10.13.1

My question: is exporting images supported for HTML/XHTML, and if so, what am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you running the exact example from the linked page, do you have a `cow.png` image in the current directory?

Comment: Yes, I have a cow.png file in the current directory. The graphics are presented properly in PDF, so ConTeXt is finding them.

Comment: You need to manually copy the image to `example-export/images` folder. Then everything should work correctly. A [similar question](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/081409.html) was asked on the context mailing list, where Wolfgang's reply was to manually copy the images.

Comment: Great. That fixed it. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Aditya Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Images are not copied automatically. I assume that the rationale is that one might want different resolution images for print and web. So, you have to manually copy (or convert) the images and place them in the `filename-export/images` folder.

Also see [this thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2015/081409.html) on the context mailing list for related discussion.