# ConTeXt to HTML conversion for multiple math-heavy documents

Tags: context, unicode-math, conversion, html, mathjax

My primary goal is to convert my extremely math-heavy writings in ConTeXt to HTML so that I can put them up on the internet. I followed this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55945/16796) by @[Marco](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5245/marco), but all my mathematics comes up as plain text, rendering them unreadable.

@[Aditya](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) commented below the answer to include the MathJax JS library. Can someone explain how to do it?

From what I understood, I have to include a link to the JS library in each header file. Is there an automated way to do it? I have a lot of files, so adding a header in each file, especially after each update of the file, seems infeasible.

Also, can I use [KaTeX](https://katex.org/) instead of MathJax? If so, how?

P.S.

1. I have a project structure set up, so I would ideally like to add something to my environment file to automate the process.
2. If it is relevant, I use a lot of Unicode symbols.
3. I would have liked to add a comment to the referenced answer, but unfortunately my reputation is too low. :(

Comment: @Fran: Pandoc does not have a `context` reader.

Comment: True, I did not remember that pandoc can write but not read context. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a minimal example:

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]

\starttext

Here is a sample of a math document which has some random $x = a +
\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ inline math and some random display math
\startformula
  A = B + C + \frac{A}{B} + \binom{C}{D} 
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

Let's say this is called `test.tex`. When you run `context test.tex`, you will get a directory `test-export` with the following content:

```
test-export
├── images
├── styles
│   ├── test-defaults.css
│   ├── test-images.css
│   ├── test-styles.css
│   └── test-templates.css
├── test-div.html
├── test-pub.lua
├── test-raw.xml
└── test-tag.xhtml

2 directories, 8 files
```

The file `test-div.html` looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>

<!--

    input filename   : test
    processing date  : 2020-05-19T02:34:41-04:00
    context version  : 2020.05.09 15:37
    exporter version : 0.35

-->



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <title>test</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/test-defaults.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/test-images.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/test-styles.css" />


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="document" xmlns="http://www.pragma-ade.com/context/export">

<div class="warning">Rendering can be suboptimal because there is no default/fallback css loaded.</div>

<div>

Here is a sample of a math document which has some random <m:math display="inline" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><m:mrow><m:mi></m:mi><m:mo>=</m:mo><m:mi></m:mi><m:mo>+</m:mo><m:msqrt><m:mfrac><m:mn>1</m:mn><m:mn>2</m:mn></m:mfrac></m:msqrt></m:mrow></m:math> inline math and some random display math
 <div class="formula">
  <div class="formulacontent n-1">
   <m:math display="block" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <m:mrow>
     <m:mi></m:mi>
     <m:mo>=</m:mo>
     <m:mi></m:mi>
     <m:mo>+</m:mo>
     <m:mi></m:mi>
     <m:mo>+</m:mo>
     <m:mfrac>
      <m:mi></m:mi>
      <m:mi></m:mi>
     </m:mfrac>
     <m:mo>+</m:mo>
     <m:mrow>
      <m:mo>(</m:mo>
      <m:mfrac>
       <m:mi></m:mi>
       <m:mi></m:mi>
      </m:mfrac>
      <m:mo>)</m:mo>
     </m:mrow>
    </m:mrow>
   </m:math>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

A couple of things to note:

- The math content is tagged using `m:math`, `m:mi`, etc. This `m` prefix is hard-coded into the exporter and there is no way to avoid it. In principle, it should be possible to configure `mathjax` or `katex` to parse the elements inside `m:math` as math, but I don't know them well enough to know how to do that. So, for the time being, I am removing all the `m:` prefixes using sed:

  ```
   sed --in-place --expression='s/<m:/</g;s/<\/m:/<\//g' test-export/test-div.html
  ```
- The MathML export uses unicode math symbols.
- There are some bugs in the export. For example, the export of `\binom` should use `<mfrac linethickness="0">` rather than `<mfrac>`. These are relatively easy to fix but it also shows that mathml export is not used commonly enough for all these minor bugs to have been caught so far.

Currently, there is no interface for adding `js` files to the export. So, you either have to add that manually, or via a command line script. For mathjax, I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>
```

between the `<head> ... </head>` tags. The output on Firefox (on Linux) looks as follows:

[image]

For KaTeX, add the following lines (instead of the mathjax code)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-zB1R0rpPzHqg7Kpt0Aljp8JPLqbXI3bhnPWROx27a9N0Ll6ZP/+DiW/UqRcLbRjq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-y23I5Q6l+B6vatafAwxRu/0oK/79VlbSz7Q9aiSZUvyWYIYsd+qj+o24G5ZU2zJz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The output on Firefox looks as follows:

[image]

To my eyes, the mathjax output looks significantly nicer. But test around with your documents and see what you get.

Comment: That clarifies a lot.

In theory, I feel that I can write a wrapper script to run context, remove the `m:`s, and add the math typesetting library (MathJax/KaTeX), but all this seems too much hassle. The overall process still seems very inconvenient for a large project (the kind I have now).

In any case, thanks a lot! :)